# Two lines prevent reaching to a specific XML node using Python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

To reach a specific node in python I would do something like this `nodeZ = xmlDoc.find("X/Y/Z")` This works pretty good with me.

However, when I have the **following two lines** at the *beginning* of the XML file, I'm unable to select or reach nodes anymore. ***What should I do?***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE raml SYSTEM 'raml20.dtd'>
```

BTW, I'm loading the lxml package

**Update: A real exmaple**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE raml SYSTEM 'raml20.dtd'>
<raml version="2.0" xmlns="raml20.xsd">
  <cmData type="actual">
    <header>
      <log dateTime="2015-10-13T15:57:06" action="created" appInfo="ActualExporter">InternalValues are used</log>
    </header>
    <managedObject class="MRBTS" version="XXX" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-XXX" id="111">
    </managedObject>
  </cmData>
</raml>
```

And I try to reach the managedObject node by doing:

```
from lxml import etree
xmlDoc = etree.parse("D:/File.xml")
moNode = xmlDoc.find("cmData/managedObject")
```

And as I mentioned above, it only works well if I delete the first two lines.

Comment: Could you paste a real sample of your XML?

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. Please check the update

Comment: You should use an [appropriate library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse XML,

Comment: @Pynchia, but how do you explain this two lines existence effect? I parse `etree.parse("D:/File.xml")`

Comment: I am sorry. I thought you were using string find...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem. The presence or absence of the first two lines (the XML declaration and the document type declaration) does not matter. The element is simply not found.

What matters is that the XML document is in a namespace. The namespace name (`raml20.xsd`) is a little unusual, but it is OK. The following prints the wanted element:

```
from lxml import etree

xmlDoc = etree.parse("File.xml")
moNode = xmlDoc.find("r:cmData/r:managedObject", namespaces={"r": "raml20.xsd"})
print moNode
```

In the above code, a prefix (`r`) is used. An alternative is to use the namespace name (enclosed in curly braces) directly:

```
moNode = xmlDoc.find("{raml20.xsd}cmData/{raml20.xsd}managedObject")
```

A wildcard also works:

```
moNode = xmlDoc.find("{*}cmData/{*}managedObject")
```

In all three cases, the output is this:

```
<Element {raml20.xsd}managedObject at 0x2787c60>
```

More information: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces.

Comment: Thanks much, buddy. This namespace thing was an enlightenment for me. Danke :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
from lxml import etree, html

text = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE raml SYSTEM 'raml20.dtd'>
<raml version="2.0" xmlns="raml20.xsd">
  <cmData type="actual">
    <header>
      <log dateTime="2015-10-13T15:57:06" action="created" appInfo="ActualExporter">InternalValues are used</log>
    </header>
    <managedObject class="MRBTS" version="XXX" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-XXX" id="111">
    </managedObject>
  </cmData>
</raml>"""

html_code = etree.HTML(text)
result = etree.tostring(html_code, pretty_print=True, method="html")
tree = html.fromstring(result)

data = tree.xpath('//raml/cmdata/managedobject')[0]

managed_object_class = data.xpath('@class')[0]
managed_object_version = data.xpath('@version')[0]
managed_object_distname = data.xpath('@distname')[0]
managed_object_id = data.xpath('@id')[0]

print "Id: {}".format(managed_object_id)
print "Class: {}".format(managed_object_class)
print "Version: {}".format(managed_object_version)
print "DistName: {}".format(managed_object_distname)
```

**Output:**

```
Id: 111
Class: MRBTS
Version: XXX
DistName: PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-XXX
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But could you please clarify why my way works only if remove the two lines. 

Also, why did you parse xml data as a text and not as a file?

Comment: Do you want me to create a file and store that XML data inside and read it from my code? That's irrelevant. Regarding why your code works only by removing those two lines, I don't know, maybe it is because you need to use: **`xmlDoc.tostring(etree.parse("D:/File.xml"))`** instead of **`xmlDoc = etree.parse("D:/File.xml")`**